# Is many-valued logic more powerful than two-valued logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I took a logics course this semester and I am still rather unsure about some basics.

Generally speaking, is many-valued logic more powerful than two-valued logic?

By powerful I mean: is there a many-valued logic expression that cannot be represented with two valued logic? (just like you can represent a decimal number in a binary system)

I am very sorry in advance if the question is trivial or obvious and hope you may help me.

greets,
Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the semantic point of view, many valued logic (ML) is more expressive than bivalent logic (BL). ML is a semantic system (an interpreted formal language) in which any sentence can have more than two semantic values. It includes all BL type systems. Basically you can use it to describe a larger set of domains. However that doesn’t mean that a theory of type ML is more useful or more fecund than a theory of type BL. Having more values doesn’t imply that more things can be proved, if anything is the other way around (e.g. much of mathematics is based on the law of the excluded middle and it’s not available in the ML camp).

Comment: thank you for your response

Comment: I am still a little confused by your use of the word "expressive". If there is no difference in provability, meaning theres no statement in ML that cannot be proven/shown in BL how is ML more expressive? For me it sounds like in some cases it's just more convenient to formulate certain expressions using ML, since they would require a more complicated formula in BL. What defines expressivenss?

Comment: I’m using the term “expressive” technically, meaning descriptive power wrt the world. It’s a different sense from when it is used wrt computer languages and means closeness to natural language, easiness of expression.

Comment: Let’s say you have a domain (i.e. a portion of world) where things are only partially related, between J and M, the relation P holds only to the 40%. Consider the sentence “John is the son of Mike”, to interpret it we must relate words and world, we look at the domain using our semantic rules, “John” picks J, “Mike” picks M and “is the son of” picks P. The sentence is 40% true, is not fully true and not fully false. If you use a domain of this type to build a semantic system for a language it will have to be ML. BL is no applicable to this domain, therefore it is less expressive of ML.

Comment: To further clarify the point, BL vs. ML is a semantic distinction (not a syntactic one), it pertain the connection between words and world. It isn’t a property of a language in itself. Provability is a syntactic property, but it relate to semantic because we want inference rules to be truth preserving. If you weaken the restriction on the semantic side, some inference rules may stop to be truth preserving. Some assumption on which you based your proofs may stop to be acceptable. You can say more things with your language, but your deductive system become less powerful.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you're talking about.  In other words, it depends on how you evaluate 'power'.

In terms of formal expressions in propositional logic, in other words, well-formed formula of propositional logic ('wff', hereafter), every wff from any many-valued logic which is a tautology also qualifies as a tautology in two-valued logic.  The converse does not hold.  So, the set of tautologies of any many-valued logic is a subset of the tautologies of two-valued logic for propositional logic.

On the other hand, quantification in two-valued logic is limited to universal and existential quantification.  There is no quantified such as 'very' or 'many' or 'quite a lot', which are possible in many-valued logic, especially when many-valued logic refers to a fuzzy, or in other words 'infinite-valued', logic.

So, many-valued logic has more expressive power in that it can represent more natural language expressions.  But, two-valued logic is more powerful in that it has all of the wffs of many-valued logic, but many-valued logic does not have all the wffs of two-valued logic.  Also, the notion of proof probably can more readily get analyzed in two-valued logic than in many-valued logic.

You might also want to consider intuitionistic logic, which is an infinite-valued logic.  In some respects, it has more power than two-valued logic, and in some respects it has less power than two-valued logic.

Comment: I think you're conflating a number of things. Modal logics are usually two-valued logics, and intuitionistic logic is not necessarily infinite-valued, either (and not just for the silly reason that classical logic is intuitionistic). Properly intuitionistic logic is always weaker than classical logic in a straightforward way, in that the former is a subsystem of the latter.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Wikipedia says: "A consequence of this point of view is that intuitionistic logic has no interpretation as a two-valued logic, nor even as a finite-valued logic, in the familiar sense." and "Kurt Gödel's work involving many-valued logic showed in 1932 that intuitionistic logic is not a finite-valued logic."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic

Comment: @MaliceVidrine " Properly intuitionistic logic is always weaker than classical logic in a straightforward way, in that the former is a subsystem of the latter."  That didn't hold for Lukasiewicz's formulation of intuitionistic logic: "By differentiating intuitionistic from classical connectives his perspective reverses the usual one that intuitionistic propositional calculus is poorer in theorems than classical: in Łukasiewicz's formulation it is the other way around." (the paper also confirms that)  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lukasiewicz/index.html#PolNot

Comment: You're right, I did misspeak by using the "strictly", since there is a mutual interpretation. But the Wikipedia article is either wrong, or is explaining something in a misleading manner, particularly with regard to the quotes in your second comment.